# Translate twitter usernames into twitter ID

Tags: twitter, metadata

I have an old folder containing some tweets, including metadata such as twitter screen name and twitter message IDs.

I would like to transform the twitter screen name in its numerical twitter ID so that I can't see anymore the real screen name behind it.
I've seen that there are many websites that offer this, but they usually do one by one and my list is very long.
First of all: is this legal? Second question: is there a way to obtain the ID iteratively? Is there a website / code / other that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the free public Twitter API :

- https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-show : You give a screen name to get its twitter ID.
- https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-lookup to do the same with several screen names.

Comment: is there any ready code to use with python or a tutorial to do this with Twitter API? I don't have much experience in API so it's not so easy